# How do you tile a tensor with a decreasing amount of elements/values?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For eg, if I had a tensor x as:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
```

I would like to get a tensor y as:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

I've tried using **tf.tile()** but that just copies a tensor's dimension exactly as it is. I was wondering if there is a way to do this using just Tensor Transformations without any looping structures...

Answer (score 2):

[`tf.lingalg.band_part(input, 0, -1)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matrix_band_part) will zero out the bottom left triangle of a square matrix.

So your code would be

```
tiled = tf.tile(x, (tf.shape(x)[1], 1))
tf.linalg.band_part(tiled, 0, -1)
```